# Android: How to display values in Tab Layout while passing data from it

Tags: android, tabs

I want to display my values into tab layout when clicking one item in the list. My problem is how can I pass the value into one of my tab activity(TabActivity1) to appear in the first tab in my Tablayout while it displays the tablayout.xml, because whenever I clicked an item in the list it goes to my tablayout.xml which is correct but it doesnt have any value in it. Any help would be much appreciated.

heres my code:

Main.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Main extends Activity {

public final static String TAG_RECIPE="com.example.getlistfromdb.RECIPE_NAME";
public final static String TAG_INGRIDIENTS="com.example.getlistfromdb.INGRIDIENTS";


private recipelistHelper dbrecipelistHelper = null;
private Cursor ourCursor = null;
private recipeAdapter adapter = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    try
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);

    dbrecipelistHelper = new recipelistHelper(this);

    dbrecipelistHelper.createDatabase();

    dbrecipelistHelper.openDatabase();

    ourCursor=dbrecipelistHelper.getCursor();

    startManagingCursor(ourCursor);

    adapter = new recipeAdapter(ourCursor);

    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);


    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());   

        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}


private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 

{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

    {

        Cursor selectedCursor=(Cursor)adapter.getItem(position);

        selectedCursor.moveToPosition(position);  

        String ingridients = dbrecipelistHelper.getCursor(selectedCursor);
        String name = selectedCursor.getString(
        selectedCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Recipe"));


        Intent i=new Intent(Main.this,Tab.class);
        //Intent in=new Intent(Main.this,TabActivity1.class);
        i.putExtra(TAG_INGRIDIENTS,ingridients);
        i.putExtra(TAG_RECIPE,name);
        startActivity(i);

    }

};



class recipeAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    recipeAdapter(Cursor c){
        super(Main.this, c);
    }

    @Override
    public  void bindView (View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c)
    {
        recipeHolder holder = (recipeHolder)row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, dbrecipelistHelper);
    }
    @Override
    public  View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
        recipeHolder holder = new recipeHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return(row);
    }


}

static class recipeHolder {
    private TextView name=null;

    recipeHolder(View row){
        name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.recipeText);
    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, recipelistHelper r){
        name.setText(r.getName(c));
    }
}
}
```

other method in this main class come from dbhelper class

Tab.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class Tab extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
    TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
    TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third tab");

    tab1.setIndicator("Recipe");
    tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,TabActivity1.class));

    tab2.setIndicator("Facts");
    tab2.setContent(new Intent(this,TabActivity2.class));

    tab3.setIndicator("background");
    tab3.setContent(new Intent(this,TabActivity3.class));

    /** Add the tabs  to the TabHost to display. */
    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    tabHost.addTab(tab3);


}

}
```

TabActivity1

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class TabActivity1 extends  Activity {

String recipeName = null;
String ingridients = null;
String procedure = null;

private TextView txtIngridients = null;
private TextView txtName = null;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    recipeName=this.getIntent().getStringExtra(Main.TAG_RECIPE);
    ingridients=this.getIntent().getStringExtra(Main.TAG_INGRIDIENTS);

    txtName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    txtIngridients=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ingridientText);


    txtName.setText(recipeName);
    txtIngridients.setText(ingridients);


}
}
```

Comment: first put bundle data in intent and then set it to tab1.setContent() method.

Comment: @Harry: Thanks. But which bundle data I'm going to put in intent? Can you give a sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass bundle data in intent like:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,TabActivity1.class);
intent1.putExtra(Main.TAG_RECIPE, value);
intent1.putExtra(Main.TAG_INGRIDIENTS, value);
tab1.setContent(intent1);
```

Comment: Ok where should I put this? In the Main class or in the Tab class

Comment: Obviously in Tab class.

Comment: How Am I supposed to get the value? when I declare it under the method onClickList in the Main class

Comment: You have already passed values in Main class just get it by getIntent in Tab class and pass it to the the tabactivity.